# Centos 7 with custom built GLFW binary /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(init.c.o): unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section `.text'

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, cmake, linker

Note I'm using Centos 7 with `source scl_soruce enable devtoolset-6` and the rehl elrepo Nvidia drivers (with disabled noveau).  The gcc and g++ version through devtoolset-6 are apparently `GNU 6.2.1`

Note I also use libc version `ldd (GNU libc) 2.17`

I was following [this tutorial on opengl](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/OpenGL) but now I'm stuck.  I downloaded the source from [glfw's](http://www.glfw.org/download.html) website, and followed the tutorial to build (and saw no errors). I tried this with both the source provided and the master build from the repo with the same result.

I extracted the source file into Home directory, ran `cmake .` inside, then ran `make` then ran `sudo make install` and no errors occurred.

Note I also used the glad utility described in the tutorial, using opengl 3.3,

My file structure is like so:

```
cmake-build-debug
    ...
include
    glad
    KHR
CMakeLists.txt
glad.c
main.cpp
```

Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(opengltest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
include_directories("include/")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp glad.c)
add_executable(opengltest ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(opengltest -L/usr/local/lib -lglfw3 -pthread -lGLU -lGL -lrt -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXinerama -lX11 -ldl)
```

and here is the exact output I'm getting:

```
/home/centos/IDE/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/centos/IDEProjects/opengltest/cmake-build-debug --target opengltest -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target opengltest
gmake[3]: Warning: File `../include/KHR/khrplatform.h' has modification time 17724 s in the future
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/opengltest.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/opengltest.dir/glad.c.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable opengltest
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(init.c.o): unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [opengltest] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/opengltest.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/opengltest.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [opengltest] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this has to do with a frustrating on going problem Centos 7 has... Centos 7 had such an old version of g++ I was forced to use dev-toolset-6 in order to get a modern version of g++ ie one that supported c++14.  This was unrelated to the current project (which I clearly was using c++11 with) but the thing about Clion is that by default it uses uses the g++/gcc/gmake version found in /usr/bin/  which is *not* where the g++ 6.2.1 version is located.

I had already fixed this issue with projects that used C++14, go into settings for the project you want, and paste the following line in CMake options underneath Build, Execution, Deployment:

```
-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/g++ -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/gcc
```

This is the correct location of g++ now.  Of course I could do some symbolic linking to fix it, but I had previously assumed that my solution to finding the correct version in terminal (modifying .bashrc) would work for clion as well.

When I tested c++14 features on a whim it was clear this didn't work.

Now why this was an issue?  I was using two *very* different versions of g++/gcc, I used g++/gcc 6.2.1 to compile my GLFW, and used 4.7 or something to compile my actual program. That is why I was getting this strange error.

Note that this only fixes the odd .txt issue, my cmake file was also incorrect, as I forgot to target Xcursor.  The new cmake file now looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(opengltest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
include_directories("include/")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp glad.c)
add_executable(opengltest ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(opengltest -L/usr/local/lib -lglfw3 -pthread -lGLU -lGL -lrt -lX11 -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lXxf86vm -lXcursor -ldl)
```

And I now have no errors (well I still git that odd warning with clock skew, I just assume there's something wrong with GLAD websystem)

Comment: Nice investigation.